# When will subscriber status callbacks be available in ROS2?

Tags: ros2, publisher, callback, rclcpp, subscribers

What are the plans for implementing rclcpp subscriber status callbacks (connect/disconnect) in ROS2? I found this ROS1 feature quite handy.

Note that this question has [been asked before](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/implementing-subscriberstatuscallback-within-ros2) but since that was nearly 6 years ago I was wondering whether this will ever happen? It's a pretty fundamental feature that would spare many of us from writing a polling loop.